# Workflow Foundation on Linux

Tags: workflow-foundation, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, .net-4.6

I have been reading about Visual Studio 2015, ASP.Net 5, .net Core and .net framework 4.6, but cannot find if all of those cross-platform technologies will allow to run a Workflow Foundation service in Linux platforms. Please comment if this is possible and how to do it.

Comment: Workflow foundation was all about the Sharepoint, wasn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The Workflow Foundation is considered Framework Class Library (in opposition to Base Class Library). It is in version 3.5 and 4.5 [published](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource) as reference source on Github.

To my understanding, Microsoft currently does not put any effort into porting the libraries to .Net Core but there is a [ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2394) which also discusses details.

Update SEP 2017: There is a private initiative of the original WF maintainers to port wf to corefx. Far from ready.

https://github.com/dmetzgar/corewf